# Kotlin - nullable receiver extension won't accept non-nullable equivalent

Tags: kotlin, covariance

Consider the following example:

```
class Foo<T>

fun <T> Foo<Iterable<T>?>.bar(i: Iterable<T>) {
    ...
}
```

Class `Foo` has an extension method, `bar` which requires a receiver of `Iterable<T>?`

Consider the following use-case:

```
val x = listOf(123, 456)
val f = Foo<Iterable<Int>>()

f.bar(x)
```

Compiler error on `f`:

> Type mismatch
>
> Required: Foo<Iterable<Int>?>
>
> Found: Foo<Iterable<Int>>

I could understand this not working the other way around, trying to pass a nullable type to a non-nullable receiver, but I don't understand why I can't pass a non-nullable to a nullable receiver.

Essentially I'm trying to say "The receiver may be null, but in this case, I can guarantee it isn't"

Any thoughts on how to fix this, so the extension method will allow both nullable and non-nullable types?

**Note:** I cannot change `val f = Foo<Iterable<Int>>` to `val f = Foo<Iterable<Int>?>` because this is automatically decided based on the type of a property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `out` modifier and it will work:

```
class Foo<out T>
```

We use `out` modifier to indicate **covariance** (similar to "? extends T" in Java). **Covariance** - is the ability to change the generic type argument from a class to one of its parents, i.e. assign `List<String>` to `List<Any>`.

Here are docs about [generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).

Comment: Inspired, sir! I completely forgot about variance. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to @Sergey's answer, you can employ [use-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) rather than [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) (as `class Foo<out T>` will limit the use of `T` and affect all usages) and add the `out` modifier at the extension declaration:

```
fun <T> Foo<out Iterable<T>?>.bar(i: Iterable<T>) { /* ... */ }
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)</sup>

The `out` modifier means that the extension will accept not just exactly `Foo<Iterable<T>?>` but any subtype of nullable `Iterable` typed with `T` as well, such as `List<T>?`, `Set<T>?`, and also, as not-null types are treated as subtypes of the nullable ones, the extension will accept not-null counterparts of the `Iterable` types.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect that Hotkey and Sergey described like this:

```
fun <T, S: Iterable<T>?> Foo<S>.bar(i: Iterable<T>) { /* ... */ }
```

It is more redundant but might be easier to understand. Since you define `Iterable<T>?` as upper bound of `S`, any subtype including `Iterable<T>` is allowed now too.

After grasping the concept, I would still go with `out Iterable<T>?` because it more concise.