# Accept both generic of nullable type and non-nullable type in function argument

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to write a function that accepts both `Container<V?>` and `Container<V>`.

```
interface Container<V>{
    var value: V
}

class ContainerA(override var value: Boolean) : Container<Boolean>
class ContainerB(override var value: Boolean?): Container<Boolean?>

fun test(container: Container<Boolean?>){
    val currentValue = container.value
    if(currentValue != null){
        processValue(currentValue)
    } else {
        print("not set")
    }
}

fun processValue(b: Boolean){
    print(b)
}

val t = test(ContainerB(null))
val t2 = test(ContainerA(false))
```

However, I get the following compile time error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Container<Boolean?>
Found:
ContainerA
```

In my mind, if I handle `<Container<V?>`, `Container<V>` should also be handled. Trying `ContainerA(false) as Container<Boolean?>` results in a `Unchecked cast: ContainerA to Container<Boolean?>` warning.

Edit:

If I create 2 separate functions, I get a `Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature` error.

```
interface Container<V>{
    var value: V
}

class A(override var value: Boolean?) : Container<Boolean?>
class B(override var value: Boolean) : Container<Boolean>

fun test(
    container: Container<Boolean>
){
    println(container.value)
    container.value = false
}

fun test(
    container: Container<Boolean?>
){
    println(container.value)
    container.value = null
}

fun main(){
    test(A(true))
    test(B(false))
}
```

Comment: How is this question not a duplicate of the question you linked in your answer?

Comment: @Tenfour04 It is slightly different because I wanted to support getters and setters `var`, but I don't think it's feasible. Is it not worth it to keep duplicate questions if the phrasing and explanation is different?

Comment: Duplicate questions are kept, and they link to the question they are a duplicate of. It makes it easier to find all the answers in one place. Duplicates can be a good thing because slight differences make it more searchable. IMO this is close enough to be a duplicate of that other question. Properties are really just functions with syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I realized that adding `out` isn't enough since it doesn't work with setters, so technically the answer no longer works. And creating 2 separate functions results in a JVM error. I found a workaround with `in` and casting, but I am not sure about the unintended consequences of `container.value as Boolean?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covariance (`out`) cannot work and doesn't make sense if you want to also be able to put something **in**to the container (setting the `var`).

So, the only option then is to overload the function. But as you found, overloads where the only difference in the signature is the generic type will clash with each other on the JVM due to type erasure.

You can work around this by using `@JvmName` to provide an alternate name for the overload when it is called from Java. In Kotlin you can still use the given name of the function.

```
fun test(
    container: Container<Boolean>
){
    println(container.value)
    container.value = false
}

@JvmName("testNullable")
fun test(
    container: Container<Boolean?>
){
    println(container.value)
    container.value = null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54377747/20898396) answer, add the `out` keyword `fun test(container: Container<out Boolean?>)`.

> First, generic types in Java are invariant, meaning that List<String>
> is not a subtype of List<Object> ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance))

`V` is a subtype of `V?`, and to include subtypes, you need to do something like `<? extends V>`, which is done with the `out` keyword.

The warning is because of type erasure, which improves performance ([source](https://medium.com/javarevisited/understanding-type-erasure-in-java-generics-851277a39e72)). (casts happen at runtime, but type information is erased by that point)

> The type safety checks that Kotlin performs for generic declaration
> usages are done at compile time. At runtime, the instances of generic
> types do not hold any information about their actual type arguments.
> The type information is said to be erased. For example, the instances
> of Foo<Bar> and Foo<Baz?> are erased to just Foo<*>.

However, it doesn't work with setters.

```
interface Container<V>{
    var value: V
}

class A(override var value: Boolean?) : Container<Boolean?>
class B(override var value: Boolean) : Container<Boolean>

fun test(
    t: Container<out Boolean?>
){
    t.value = null
}
```

```
Setter for 'value' is removed by type projection
```

This should work, but I doubt it's good practice (and you can't set to null):

```
interface Container<V>{
    var value: V
}

class A(override var value: Boolean?) : Container<Boolean?>
class B(override var value: Boolean) : Container<Boolean>

fun test(
    container: Container<in Boolean>
){
    val value = container.value as Boolean?
    println("$value ${container.value}")
    // container.value = null
}

fun main(){
    test(A(true))
    test(B(false))
}
```

Comment: Type erasure isn't for performance...it's for backward compability.